Leetcode 235 Lowest Common Ancestor of a Binary Search Tree
I am trying to solve LeetCode problem 235. Lowest Common Ancestor of a Binary Search Tree:

Given a binary search tree (BST), find the lowest common ancestor (LCA) node of two given nodes in the BST.
According to the definition of LCA on Wikipedia: “The lowest common ancestor is defined between two nodes p and q as the lowest node in T that has both p and q as descendants (where we allow a node to be a descendant of itself).”

My code is as follows:

class Solution:
    def lowestCommonAncestor(self, root: 'TreeNode', p: 'TreeNode', q: 'TreeNode') -> 'TreeNode':
        ans = None

        def travel(root, p, q, ans):
            if not root: return
            temp=[]
            if root:
                temp.append(root.val)
            if root.right:
                temp.append(root.right.val)
            if root.left:
                temp.append(root.left.val)
            if p.val in temp and q.val in temp:
                ans = root
            if ans:
                return ans
            travel(root.left, p, q, ans)
            travel(root.right, p, q, ans)

        return travel(root, p, q, ans)

It failed to pass this test case:


Input: root = [6,2,8,0,4,7,9,null,null,3,5], p = 2, q = 4
Output: 2
Explanation: The LCA of nodes 2 and 4 is 2, since a node can be a descendant of itself according to the LCA definition.

Can someone explain why my code returns None for the above given input?
It showed the right answer when I tried print(ans). What is my mistake?

You never use the results of the recursions. The only time travel returns anything other than None is when it has passed through ans = root. (And the ans argument is always None.)

You don't use temp. You can see other users solutions on leetcode and figure out how to solve this problem

@IvanSharapenkov if p.val in temp and q.val in temp: is right there.

@molbdnilo and on this stage temp always contain [root.val, right.val, left.val]. That's not make sence

You also don't use information that this tree is actually binary search tree

@IvanSharapenkov It doesn't contain that when either root.left or root.right is None.

@molbdnilo, I'm quite sure Ivan knows that.

@molbdnilo you are right. But there is still nothing even near solution. Idea behind this code makes no sense from the point of view of solving the "Lowest Common Ancestor of a Binary Search Tree" problem. Probably author could use temp array for solution but currently it's useless because he doesn't pass it two next function call or return. He doesn't use it in other words

There are several issues:

First the answer to "why my code return null ... It showed the right answer when I tried print(ans)": this is because you lose the value of ans when you come back from a recursive call. There are two reasons why you lose it:

These recursive calls may return the value you need, but your code ignores what is returned by them. The caller will then return None, even though the recursive call might have returned the value you needed. You'd want to do something like ans = travel(root.left, p, q, ans), and then check what ans is, and if it is not None, return it, ...etc.

You seem to think that an assignment to ans will also update the ans that the caller has as (parameter) variable. But that is not true. Each execution of travel has its own ans local variable, and assigning to one does not update the other. It doesn't help to pass ans as argument. You might as well drop that parameter.



temp will collect three values at the most, which are within the same parent-child "family": you'll only detect a common ancestor (after fixing the first problem) when p and q are either in a direct parent-child relationship, or are direct siblings. If p and q are further apart, they will never be collected in the same temp list, and so you'll not find any common parent. For instance, your code will fail when you give this input: [1,null,2,null,3] and p=1 and q=3.

Your code does not use the fact that the given binary tree is a binary search tree. By using this property, you can avoid traversing into both a left and right subtree, and immediately choose the right one.


Here is a description of the algorithm you could use:

If the values of both p and q are less than the value of the given root, then you know that both p and q are in the left subtree below that root (BST property). Then the root is not the closest common ancestor, as certainly root.left is closer. You can recursively solve the problem with root.left as new root.

Similarly if both p and q have values that are greater than the value of the root, you can recur to root.right.

If neither of the above conditions is true, then we have a situation where one of p and q is in the left subtree of the root and the other in the right subtree. There is also a boundary case where either p or q is the root itself. But in all these cases root is a common ancestor where we know that neither root.left nor root.right is a common ancestor, and so the current root is the node we want to return.


Here is a spoiler implementation:

 def lowestCommonAncestor(self, root: 'TreeNode', p: 'TreeNode', q: 'TreeNode') -> 'TreeNode':
     if root:
         if root.val > max(p.val, q.val):
             return self.lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, p, q)
         if root.val < min(p.val, q.val):
             return self.lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, p, q)
     return root


It's not strictly necessary to use the BST property. The standard RMQ solution will pass without additional thinking (though it is overkill).

Yes, I notice that passes the tests, which seems to indicate that the tests could be made more challenging, more so because LeetCode 236 (the next challenge) drops the assumption of a BST.

Thank you for your answer. I was not aware those concepts. Will study more so I can be great like you!
